# Values from (incorrectly used?) Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a bag of 15 coins:

```
 5 of which are   fair coins with P(Heads) = 0.5  
10 of which are unfair coins with P(Heads) = 0.8
```

We select a coin at random, flip it, recorded the result of the flip, then returned the coin to the bag.
We do this a total of 6 times, and recorded 4 heads.

I've worked out that for any individual trial, P(Heads) is 0.7

So, out of curiosity, I applied Bayes' theorem:

```
P(Fair|4/6 Heads) = P(4/6 Heads|Fair) * P(Fair) / P(4/6 Heads)
```

P(4/6 Heads|Fair) = $\binom{6}{4}*0.5^{6}$
P(Fair) = $\frac{1}{3}$
P(4/6 Heads) = $\binom{6}{4}*0.7^{4}*0.3^{2}$

P(Fair|4/6 Heads) = 0.241026 = 24.1026%

I'm puzzled as to what that value of 24.1026% represents.
Initially, I thought that it must be the ratio of fair coins within the selected six coins (i.e. on average, given multiple trials which results in an outcome of 4/6 heads, 24.1026% of the 6 selected coins were fair).
So I wrote a program to test this:

> I simulated multiple trials that picks 6 coins from the bag, with the original 1/3 fair coin chance.
>   I kept a count for each trial which resulted in 4/6 Heads, and summed up the number of fair coins in each of them.
>   Then I tried to find the ratio: $\frac{numberOfFairCoins}{6*numberOf4HeadTrials}$
>   But I got a value of 34.38% instead.

So, any ideas?

As a side note, how does one calculate that value of 34.38%?

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by the event "Fair" since the coins are being returned to the bag each flip.  If we were to ask a related question, where you -Pick a coin -Flip *that* coin (and only that coin) six times and record results, you will get a more easily understandable scenario.  Indeed, that looks to be what you actually calculated.  That by picking a single coin and flipping several times, given that the outcome was 4/6 heads, there is a 24%'ish chance that the coin was one of the fair ones.

Comment: Indeed that was the original scenario/question that I encountered, and the value that I found for that particular given scenario is roughly 24.1965%, (approximately 0.09% higher that the value above). The above posted question is a variation on the scenario you described, which I was curious if is there is actually any significance to the value I calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think your $24.1026\%$ means anything.

The way I would do the calculation would be to find $P(n/6 \text{ Fair})$ with $0 \le n \le 6$ and with some effort $P(4/6 \text{ Heads}\mid n/6 \text{ Fair})$, and thus their product $P(4/6 \text{ Heads and } n/6 \text{ Fair})$.  Adding these up would give  $P(4/6 \text{ Heads})$.

Bayes' formula could then be used for  $P(n/6 \text{ Fair} \mid 4/6 \text{ Heads})$ and thus $E[n \text{ Fair} \mid 4/6 \text{ Heads}]$ which you could then divide by $6$ to give the expected proportion fair.

The numbers I get are

```
 n P(n Fair)   P(4H|nF) P(4H & nF)   P(nF|4H) 
 0 0.087791495 0.245760 0.0215756379 0.066563740
 1 0.263374486 0.307200 0.0809086420 0.249614025
 2 0.329218107 0.345600 0.1137777778 0.351019723
 3 0.219478738 0.348000 0.0763786008 0.235638240
 4 0.082304527 0.322500 0.0265432099 0.081889367
 5 0.016460905 0.281250 0.0046296296 0.014283029
 6 0.001371742 0.234375 0.0003215021 0.000991877
```

$\sum_n P(4/6 \text{ Heads and } n/6 \text{ Fair})$ is thus $0.324135$ as you calculated more directly.

This gives $E[n \text{ Fair} \mid 4/6 \text{ Heads}] = 2.063492$ and dividing this by $6$ gives $0.3439153$ and your simulated result of $34.38\%$ is very close to this.

Comment: Two uncommented downvotes in the first minute!

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening answer, I found it very instructive. I would need to further study probabilities to fully understand your solution, as I couldn't figure out a graceful way to generate the values of P(4H|nF), as per your table. That aside, the rest makes perfect sense.

Comment: @testblank: For `P(4H|nF)`, I had to consider how many heads could come from the fair coins and how many from the unfair coins, and add up the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

$P(\text{Fair}\mid \text{4/6 Heads})= P(\text{4/6 Heads}|\text{Fair}) \cdot P(\text{Fair}) / P(\text{4/6 Heads})$ is meaningless.

From the values you used, that's the probability that 4 of 6 coins are heads if they are *all* fair times the probability that *one* coin is fair divided by the probability that 4 of 6 coins are heads when you *are returning* the coins to the bag after each flip.   That makes no sense at all.

This has more meaning.
$$P(\text{All Fair}\mid \text{4/6 Heads})= P(\text{4/6 Heads}|\text{All Fair}) \cdot P(\text{Fair})^\color{red}{6} / P(\text{4/6 Heads})$$

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Using the above corrected formula, the probability that all our selected coins were fair, given that we flipped 4/6 heads, is 0.000991877 (which checks out with Henry's table). Thanks for the answer.